# How to change passphrase by pasting a new long character string into the gpg-agent

Tags: 16.04, encryption, gnupg, passwd, passphrase

I have a DELL XPS running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The copy and paste function appears to be disabled when using the gpg-agent. Using gpg2, how can one copy and paste a long passphrase from a text file into the gpg-agent to encrypt a file and then copy and paste another passphrase required to sign the file?

If this is still unclear, my apologies --have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to copy my pgp passphrase to the clipboard before executing in Terminal the following:
gpg2 --force-mdc --symmetric --sign 'filename'

Then when the gpg-agent dialogue appears, use an arbitrary dummy passphrase such as 'b2c3d4e5'

Then when the gpg-agent asks for your secret passphrase to sign the file, you can paste the passphrase you copied to the clipboard.

Now you have the file encrypted and signed with the dummy passphrase.

Next you can copy from a plaintext file to the clipboard the passphrase that you want to use to encrypt the original 'filename'

Then repeat the command:
gpg2 --force-mdc --symmetric --sign 'filename'

This will again call up the gpg-agent dialogue and you can paste the longer secure passphrase (twice).

gpg will not require your secret key for signing the file on the second pass since the initial entry suffices for some time during the session.

Terminal will return the message:
'filename'.gpg' exists. Overwrite? (y/N)

To which you simply reply 'y'
and the existing 'filename'.gpg will be overwritten with the new passphrase protected and signed version of the encrypted file.